# Autofill a textbox in function on pageload

Tags: jquery, function, pageload

My goal is to fill 3 text boxes on pageload of my program using the

functionintializeFormForDebugging()

I have able to fill them in the style part of my program here but he wants me to call them in a function instead. Here is a example of one of my text box's

```
<input id="txtCOGs" type="text" value="4000" /></td>
```

Does anyone have advice on how to do the same thing except in the function and also why put them in a function instead of just using the style to autofill the boxs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add content to a textbox using a function.

```
function addToInput(id, text) {

    $("#" + id).val(text);

}
```

To call this function you can say `addToInput("txtCOGs", "4000");` inside the document ready.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <input type="text" id="s" name="input" value="search"
      onfocus="if (this.value == 'search') {
                   this.value='' ;
                   this.style.opacity = 0.5;
                 }"
                 onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                      this.value = 'search';
                      this.style.opacity = 0.2;
                 }"/>
```

Comment: You should really separate out JavaScript from HTML

Comment: Thanks for the answer i understand what you are going for here but i don't believe i on this level quiet yet =)